# Connect to Google Cloud Datastore using dev_appserver.py & google.golang.org/appengine@v1.6.6

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

As the title says. We have a legacy Go 1.11 AppEngine API that requires the `dev_appserver.py` to run. Simply, I want `appengine.Main()` & `appengine.NewContext(r)` to allow my application to point to my Cloud Datastore using my `project-id`, rather than the local emulator's storage. I have set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to no avail.

This would be so I can locally run the server, while accessing a shared, Cloud DB.

I am using `google.golang.org/appengine@v1.6.6` w/ `dev_appserver.py --enable_console --port=8081 --support_datastore_emulator=true --go_debugging=true app.yaml`

Is this possible? Or am I stuck on a local emulator when using the old Go libraries?

Comment: Take a look at ```remote_api``` - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/go111/tools/remoteapi

Comment: Hey, thank you. This looks like the perfect resource. Just a quick question on it; should I only use `remote_api` in my code if `appengine.IsDevAppServer`? Essentially using `appengine.NewContext(r)` in production, and `remote_api.NewRemoteContext(host, hc)` in development?

Comment: I'm not sure cos it's been a very long time that I used ```remote_api``` and it was with python. If I remember correctly, it was similar to your logic i.e. I think the logic was - If I'm running on local environment, then use remote_api else default behavior (don't use remote_api kicks in)

Comment: Awesome. Sounds reasonable, thank you for sending this over. I'll get on it. You can write an answer if you want so I can accept. If not, I'll do it tomorrow or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from comments to answer

1. Take a look at `remote_api` for Go 1.11 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/go111/tools/remoteapi
2. The logic for using it would be something along the lines of -

   If running on local environment, use `remote_api` else stick to the default behavior (i.e. since `remote_api` isn't enabled, it will either use the emulator in local environments or use production data directly in production)

   To keep things simple, you could try using same variable name i.e.

   ```
   if this is local environment
    ctx, err := remote_api.NewRemoteContext(host, hc)
   else
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
   ```

   Then you use 'ctx' in the rest of your queries/calls to datastore

   **Note:** I'm not familiar with 'Go' so take the above as pseudo-code and not working code
3. You might also want to consider not running the above changes with the `--support_datastore_emulator=true` flag

Comment: Thank you, marked as accepted. I am having a weird issue with one type of HTTP POST request that's sent from my Go application. It only happens when I use the `remot_api`'s context. Why would you recommend to not run with the `support_datastore_emulator` flag? I am running with it currently. So wondering if this could be causing that behaviour.

Comment: My thoughts are ```--support_datastore_emulator``` means 'Support datastore local emulation with Cloud Datastore emulator'; I was thinking if it's off (which seems to be the default setting) then it WON'T support local emulator storage which seems to be what you want. To be clear, I'm not 100% certain of this which is why I used the phrase - 'might want to consider' :)